# How to fix InvariantViolation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid`.
I have checked all the export and the `render()` still, I am getting this issue.

Changing the `export default` and the `render()`

```
export default class CarScreen extends Component {
...
}
```

No error.

Github link to the [project](https://github.com/batman6/Cars).

Comment: How do you import the class?

Comment: ```import CarScreen from './components/CarScreen';
import CarDetailScreen from './components/CarDetailScreen';
import AddCarScreen from './components/AddCarScreen';
import EditCarScreen from './components/EditCarScreen';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Car: CarScreen,
    CarDetails: CarDetailScreen,
    AddCar: AddCarScreen,
    EditCar: EditCarScreen,
  }```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted on your github `react-native` doesn't have a component named `List`.